# AppCompactv21 Toolbar as ActionBar theming has no affect

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have followed guide http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html and implemented Toolbar as ActionBar but i cant seem to change theme of Toolbar. I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light as my app's base theme and would like to style/theme toolbar/actionbar individually.

Adding styles to my app_coomon_toolbar_xml has no affect at all
For example when I add below

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

to app_common_toolbar.xml theme of it does not change and it still is picked from main app theme which is Theme.AppCompat.Light.

Only when I change App base theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, Toolbar theme changes. I don't want to do that.
What am I doing wrong?

---

Here are details of my my Toolbar and how I load it

app_common_toolbar.xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/    android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_common_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
/>
```

MainActivity.java
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_common_toolbar);

    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to call `setSupportActionBar` then your theme shouldn't have an actionbar.

Comment: do you mean i should not use theme with action bar like ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar?

Comment: Try it your way. You will get an error on your `setSupportActionBar` telling you that you already have a action bar.

Comment: no it doesn't and it works fine

Comment: Then that's cool. for reference: http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html `To use Toolbar as an Action Bar, first disable the decor-provided Action Bar.`

Comment: I have already read and linked to it at the top and read To use ".. first disable the decor-provided Action Bar.." part but, if i extend my base theme from an app compact theme that has no actionbar, app crashes when i want to do anything with action bar

Comment: Not sure how is that possible. Check my template here `https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template`. It uses themes with no action bar.

Comment: A lot clear now!  setSupportActionBar(toolbar) was working because there was null check! Silly me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per  Pedro Oliveira's comments, I was doing null check for actionbar so, setSupportactionBar wasn't even called. I now able to make required changes by following his example on Github

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way:

`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="72dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbartitle"
        app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarSubtitle"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:title="@string/location_placeholder"
        />`

and defined colors.xml like

```
    <resources>
      <color name="primaryColor_500">#03a9f4</color>
      <color name="primaryDarkColor_700">#0288d1</color>    
    </resources>
```

and finally style.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor_700</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps u!

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar causes crashas i try to set actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)